# Uploading in Carto changes column order

Tags: carto

Has anyone noticed that *sometimes* when uploading to Carto via the app (my tests are just from CSV) the column order is different from source, and sometimes it isn't??

I have not noticed the same problem uploading directly via the SQL API, but have not tested extensively.

Question: is there any way I control whether column order is kept intact when uploading?

Context: I'd like to standardise an update process where a new table is uploaded then the existing table is truncated and values populated from the newly uploaded table. A la:

```
TRUNCATE table;
INSERT INTO table
SELECT * FROM newtable;
```

This does not work if the columns are in a different order - I get a type error because the index is pointing to the wrong column!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of * type your column names explicitly. That way you have full control:

```
TRUNCATE table;
INSERT INTO table
SELECT id, geom, col3, col4, col5 FROM newtable;
```

Make sure it corresponds with your table format.

Answer (score 0):

CARTO is using Postgres and that database engine does not guarantee any ordering on the columns when using `*`. In your `SELECT` queries you should make explicit which columns and in which order you want them.